# Type of styled-components in react

Tags: react-redux, flowtype, styled-components

i use styled-components in my project. And have this component

```
const Title = styled.h1`
  font-size: 1.5em;
  text-align: center;
  color: #000;
`;
```

and i don't know what type i need to add for this component 
Title: React$ComponentType<`any`>   work, but put any is bad idea i think.

i search my problem and find this

```
type StyleValue = {[key: string]: Object} | number | false | null;
type StyleProp = StyleValue | Array<StyleValue>;
```

but it for react-native, and i can't update it for my project

Comment: Since you are already initialising `Title` to a styled component, you do need to provide a type for it. Are you trying to provide a type definition for props passed to it?

Comment: @BoyWithSilverWings yes, exactly, but don't sure about second part, i need provide a type definition for Title and his props

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you are asking but I will give an example in the hope it will help you're understanding. Please provide more information. Below I have my `Title` component

```
const Title = ({
  text,
  textColor,
}) => {
  return (
    <StyledTitle textColor={color}>
      {text}
    </StyledTitle>
  );
};

Title.propTypes = {
  text: PropTypes.string,
  textColor: PropTypes.string,
};

export default Title;
```

Using `Styled-components` I then have my `StyledTitle.js` file:

```
const StyledTitle = styled.h1`
  color: `${props => props.textColor} || black`;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  text-align: center;
`;

export default StyledTitle;
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: it is flow coverage question, i have const Title in my App.js file, I need a type annotation, need a more precise definition of the data type in Styled-components. all project work good